# R: Control number of histogram bins

Tags: r, histogram, bins

I am using the hist-function to analyze some data I generated. For an analysis-assay I would like to precisely control the number of histogram bins.

I know the "break-argument" and I can see that in many cases the number of bins is in a direct relationship to the number of breaks (i.e. no_bins = no_breaks + 1).

Due to R's algorithm this is not always the case. Is there a way to force R to output a specific number of bins?

Let me know if I need to specify further details.

Best and many thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931895/exact-number-of-bins-in-histogram-in-r)?

Comment: You can potentially use ggplot2 library it has a geom_histogram where you can control the number of bins using the binwidth argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?hist`, there are several options for controlling the bins through the `breaks` argument.

> `breaks` one of:
>
> a vector giving the breakpoints between histogram cells,
>
> a function to compute the vector of breakpoints,
>
> a single number giving the number of cells for the histogram,
>
> a character string naming an algorithm to compute the number of cells
>   (see ‘Details’),
>
> a function to compute the number of cells.
>
> In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only; the
>   breakpoints will be set to pretty values. If breaks is a function, the
>   x vector is supplied to it as the only argument.

For the greatest precision, you have to set the breakpoints exactly, either by supplying a vector of breakpoints, or a function to compute them. You need to cover the entire range of x with your breakpoints and there will be 1 more breakpoint than bins (i.e. no_bins + 1 = no_breaks).

Comment: Thanks I didnt see the potential of the breaks argument.. this works out for me :)